# запрос на выборку по нескольким значениям одного поля

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Добрый день!

Помогите пожалуйста!

У меня есть таблица(id, name, idGroup), и в ней мне надо выбрать юзеров, которые имеют, например, idGroup равное 1, 5, 9.

Но дело в том, что эти [1, 5, 9] приходят в массиве, либо списком.

**Вопрос:** как мне их обработать? Как вывести юзеров с таким массивом idGroup?

Answer (score 5):

Используйте `Where` и `Contains`:

```
var groups = db.Groups.Where(g => idGroups.Contains(g.IdGroup)).ToList()
```